# overlapping transparent edges in networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I have a graph in networkx with many edges that will overlap. I'm attempting to make them transparent so that the accumulation of edges will build up a darker colour, but however many edges are overlapping they are still the same shade of pale. For example with one edge:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

G = nx.Graph()

colorlist = []
G.add_edge(1,2)

# explicitly set positions
nodes = {1: (1,0),
2: (0,1)}

nx.draw_networkx(G, nodes, alpha=0.1)
ax = plt.gca()
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

this gives a faint line
[image]

but when six transparent lines are layered over each other

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

G = nx.Graph()

colorlist = []
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,2)

# explicitly set positions
nodes = {1: (1,0),
2: (0,1)}

nx.draw_networkx(G, nodes, alpha=0.1)
ax = plt.gca()
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

it looks the exact same
[image]

why does layering transparent lines over each other not make a darker line, and how can I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `MultiGraph` instead of `Graph`. Otherwise, your graph will still contain only one edge, even if you add it multiple times.

The following will create the desired image with "darker" edges:

```
G = nx.MultiGraph()

colorlist = []
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,2)

# explicitly set positions
nodes = {1: (1,0),
2: (0,1)}

nx.draw_networkx(G, nodes, alpha=0.1)
ax = plt.gca()
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```